# Can I integrate my UIAutomation Tests with XCode and set automitically run them every night?

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, ios-ui-automation

I need to know if I can do Continuous Integration with XCode server. In example: set run the tests every night or when someone commit changes, and more..

I am trying to decide one iOS Ui Automation tool to integrate with my Xcode server
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems here:

- UIAutomation has no built in support in Xcode Server. I've filed bugs, I've chased down people at WWDC. Most I've ever gotten on this problem is basically "shrug." I'm not sure UIAutomation is a priority for Apple right now. So you're not going to get any official support.
- As was noted, you might be able to use a trigger. The trigger won't be able to add anything to the Xcode Server report, besides possibly the error logging. But you're not going to get anything added to the nice report table.
- Running on actual devices has traditionally been a problem (if you care about that.) The loading the app part has been a problem for us, but Xcode Server might be able to preload the app for you. In addition, it seems like this might have changed in the iOS 8 SDK.

There is just a lot of uncertainty around this sort of workflow. I'm hoping Apple eventually makes an announcement or adds a new tool, but the best answer I've gotten is if you want to go down this path, use UI Unit Tests. That's a shame because it requires knowledge of Obj-C or Swift, and means interacting with the app at an API level instead of an abstract level, but if you're looking for the direction Apple wants to see people go, that's it.

Edit 7/4/2015: As of WWDC 2015, there is a new UI Testing component as part of Xcode 7 that, in my experience, seems totally supported, and is promising Xcode Server support. I would very strongly recommend using that, and not using the Instruments UIAutomation tool.

Comment: Which technology or method are you referring to as "UI Unit Tests"? I'm researching iOS UI tests and am trying to get a picture of the different solutions available. Thanks! (Your answer otherwise helped me a lot!)

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode6 right around the corner they are adding some features to XCode Server specifically it looks like "Triggers" will be helpful for running iOS UIAutomation tools. Since you can run UI automation scripts from cmd line it should be possible to utilize triggers to run your scripts post builds. This along side the logic for when a bot should run will let you decide if it should be nightly or on every commit.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014509-SW1

Comment: I am just commenting to confirm that you can get an Xcode Bot to run UIAutomation tests, however it is not the cleanest solution as there is no direct support for instructing a bot to execute a set of UIA test scripts. I was able to create a post build trigger that would take a build and run a UIA test script.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a framework around UIAutomation called [Illuminator](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator) to handle tasks like nightly test runs, pull request tests, and other automated conveniences.

It provides a flexible and extensible command line that can execute any particular subset of tests that you'd like, and produces reports in JUnit format (used by [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/)).

Comment: This will not solve the problem that was described by the post. Your tool will not handle the issue with Xcode server running everything from a background daemon user.

Comment: Can you provide more information about that? It wasn't clear to me from the question how their CI environment was configured. Jenkins launches our build jobs from its daemon user, so I must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: The piece you are missing is that @Colin Cornaby intends to use XCode server as their choice of CI not Jenkins.

Comment: I can look into this more when I return from travel, but is XCode server really unable to run shell scripts?

Comment: Xcode is able to run shell scripts. However the user that executes the scripts is named something like _xcdbuild and is essentially a hidden user buried in the /var directory. I did come up with a work around though, with the key part being forcing the hidden user to execute my scripts with the identity of another user.

Comment: What is the error you get when it runs with the default hidden user?